# Dojo: How to have different label and value on FilteringSelect widget when using JsonRest store?

Tags: select, dojo, label

I am using JsonRest store with FilteringSelect widget and would like to know how to have different label (human readable) and value(hidden input value). All examples are using ItemFileReaderStore for doing this and it is specified that ItemFileReaderStore will be deprecated in v2.0. 
Do I need to use ItemFileReaderStore for having value and label on FilteringSelect? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't switch to ItemFileReaderStore. You just need to define an idProperty for your JsonRest store.

```
var store = new JsonRest({
    target: "/some/resource",
    idProperty: "timeStamp"
});
```

There is an example [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atoha/qpue91L9/), but with Memory.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the example, I was using idProperty but also set the searchAttr equal to idProperty. Thanks again.